# OpenGL gradient "banding" artifacts

Tags: macos, opengl

Lately I've been trying to clean up my openGl render. I've had these artifacts for awhile now but never really paid much mind to it. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

[image]

I haven't been able to figure out whats wrong with it after a bit of research. I'm using OpenGl on OSX, but I have tried it on other systems and the same artifacts occur.

Comment: I doubt you'll get much help based on this image alone...

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL gradient banding on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669765/opengl-gradient-banding-on-android)

Comment: @mbeckish There is not a config on OSX that uses the solution of that topic.

Comment: I had smth similar.Fixed it by using floating point render target.

Answer (score 11):

What you experience is the limited dynamic range of 8 bit per channel colorspace. A simple grayscale gradient, i.e. R=B=G on a 8 bit per channel framebuffer can have only 2^8 = 256 distinct values. If you transistion between similar values (like in your picture) over a large area, the result is low dynamic range banding.

The only way to overcome this is to calculate the gradient with a larger number of bits. For purposes of displaying the image on a low dynamic range screen you can use dithering.

Comment: I thought in Opengl dithering was enabled by default

Comment: Also, The gradient image is coming from lighting, not being drawn as a gradient.

Comment: @BlueSpud: It doesn't matter what is creating the gradient, lighting or an explicit gradient. If you've got only 8 bits per channel, you can resolve only 256 shades of gray. The dithering method to be used is not specified by the OpenGL spec and may produce only localized effects. Also a null-dithering algorithm (i.e. no dither support by the implementation) is completely valid.

Comment: I'm still fairly confused on implementing dithering. I have GL_DITHER enabled and nothing is happening. Do I have to write my own dithering algorithm?

Comment: @BlueSpud: enabling GL_DITHER just enables the dither algorithm built into the OpenGL implementation being used. This may very well be a null-dither (i.e. no dithering) or localized dither. OpenGL provisions no method of changing the dither algorithm used by the stage controlled by the GL_DITHER switch. However it is perfectly possible to render into a FBO with a high dynamic range color attachment (12 bits are requried to cover the human vision grayscale dynamic range). Then in postprocessing you can implement dithering using a fragment shader sourcing the HDR image generating LDR output.

Comment: Alright, I got the dither algorithm part but the rest made no sense to me. I'm pretty new to GLSL and I don't really know how to make the shader in question or what to apply it to.

Comment: @BlueSpud: I suggest you open another question specifically: "how using OpenGL to implement postprocessing dithering?" This keeps the questions specific to a focused topic and makes them easier to search for. Usage of FBOs to render to a texture has been featured several times on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

As [explained by datenwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16005990/673852), the problem is rounding of subpixel values to 8-bit range, and no-op implementation of `GL_DITHER` on most OpenGL implementations. To alleviate this, you can do dithering as a postprocessing step (another option is to do it directly in the fragment shader for each relevant primitive). Note though, that there're some requirements on OpenGL implementation for this to be possible:

1. Support high precision texture internal formats: you must have access to extra precision of resulting colors. The more extra precision, the finer variation of colors you can render smoothly. The options are:

   - floating-point textures (requires `GL_ARB_texture_float` or OpenGL 3.0+) llike `RGBA32F`, `RGBA16F` or `R11F_G11F_B10F`
   - wider than 8 bit integral formats like `RGB10_A2` or `RGBA16`
2. FBO (`GL_ARB_framebuffer_object`): you do want to do postprocessing.
3. NPOT textures: most screens have non-power-of-two dimensions; it's even more important for windowed mode.
4. GLSL: you do want to use a shader. Another option is `GL_ARB_fragment_program`.
5. Proper support for high-precision framebuffer configurations. If you choose integral texture format like `RGBA16`, it may be silently substituted with e.g. `RGBA8` (see specification of `TexImage2D` possible internal formats).

With all this said, here's a demo using the above mentioned features (and floating-point textures to be sure of the result) allowing to compare ditherless lit gray cube with dithered one. Note that by default it gives bad results for monitors which do their own dithering due to actually being 6bpp instead of 8bpp. For 6bpp monitors define `MONITOR_6_BPP` when compiling this code.

```c
// Dithering shader implementation inspired by (and completely reworked):
// http://www.anisopteragames.com/how-to-fix-color-banding-with-dithering/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLboolean animating=GL_TRUE, dithering=GL_FALSE;

GLuint ditherProgram=0;
GLuint ditherShader=0;
GLuint frameTexture=0,bayerMatrixTexture=0;
GLuint frameFramebuffer=0, depthRenderBuffer=0;

void initDitheringShader()
{
    ditherProgram=glCreateProgram();
    ditherShader=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const char* src=
        "uniform sampler2D frame, bayerMatrix;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    vec4 color=texture2D(frame,gl_TexCoord[0].xy);\n"
        "    float bayer=texture2D(bayerMatrix,gl_FragCoord.xy/8.).r*(255./64.); // scaled to [0..1]\n"
#ifdef MONITOR_6_BPP // use this for 6 bit per subpixel monitors
        "    const float rgbByteMax=63.;\n"
#else
        "    const float rgbByteMax=255.;\n"
#endif
        "    vec4 rgba=rgbByteMax*color;\n"
        "    vec4 head=floor(rgba);\n"
        "    vec4 tail=rgba-head;\n"
        "    color=head+step(bayer,tail);\n"
        "    gl_FragColor=color/rgbByteMax;\n"
        "}\n"

        ;
    const GLint length=strlen(src);
    glShaderSource(ditherShader,1,&src,&length);
    glCompileShader(ditherShader);
    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(ditherShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
    if(!status)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to compile shader\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    glAttachShader(ditherProgram,ditherShader);
    glLinkProgram(ditherProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(ditherProgram,GL_LINK_STATUS,&status);
    if(!status)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to link shading program\n");
        exit(3);
    }
    static const char bayerPattern[] = {
        0,  32,  8, 40,  2, 34, 10, 42,  /* 8x8 Bayer ordered dithering  */
        48, 16, 56, 24, 50, 18, 58, 26,  /* pattern.  Each input pixel   */
        12, 44,  4, 36, 14, 46,  6, 38,  /* is scaled to the 0..63 range */
        60, 28, 52, 20, 62, 30, 54, 22,  /* before looking in this table */
        3,  35, 11, 43,  1, 33,  9, 41,  /* to determine the action.     */
        51, 19, 59, 27, 49, 17, 57, 25,
        15, 47,  7, 39, 13, 45,  5, 37,
        63, 31, 55, 23, 61, 29, 53, 21,};
    glGenTextures(1,&bayerMatrixTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,bayerMatrixTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 8,8, 0,GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bayerPattern);
}

void initLightAndMaterial()
{
    const GLfloat ambient[4]={0.5,0.5,0.5,1};
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, ambient);
    const GLfloat emission[4]={0.2,0.2,0.2,1};
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, emission);
    const GLfloat diffuseColor[4]={1,1,1,1};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseColor);
    const GLfloat position[4]={2,0,-2,1};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    const GLfloat globalAmbient[4]={0,0,0,1};
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT,globalAmbient);
}

void checkRequirements()
{
    if(!GL_ARB_texture_float)
    {
        fputs("Float textures are not supported, this demo relies on them\n",stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    if(!GL_ARB_framebuffer_object)
    {
        fputs("FBO is not supported, no good way to do postprocessing\n",stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    /* We need OpenGL 2.0+ for GLSL and NPOT textures.
     * Extension interface fot GL_ARB_shader_objects is too
     * different from core so not trying to use it.
     */
    if(!GLEW_VERSION_2_0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Need OpenGL>=2.0 for GLSL and NPOT textures\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

GLboolean init()
{
    checkRequirements();
    initLightAndMaterial();
    initDitheringShader();
    return 1;
}

unsigned getTime()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
    return tv.tv_usec/1000+tv.tv_sec*1000;
}

void renderScene()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    static unsigned oldTime;
    if(!oldTime) oldTime=getTime();
    const unsigned curTime=getTime();
    if(animating)
    {
        static double angle=0;
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        angle += (curTime-oldTime)%13500 * 360 / 13500.;
        glRotatef(angle,1,0,0);
        glRotatef(angle,0,1,0);
    }
    oldTime=curTime;

    typedef struct CubeVertex
    {
        GLfloat x,  y,  z;
        GLfloat nx, ny, nz;
        GLfloat u, v;
    } CubeVertex;
    static const CubeVertex vertices[] =
    {
    //   x  y  z  nx ny nz   u v
       { 1,-1,-1,  0, 0,-1,  0,1},
       { 1, 1,-1,  0, 0,-1,  0,0},
       {-1, 1,-1,  0, 0,-1,  1,0},
       {-1,-1,-1,  0, 0,-1,  1,1},

       {-1,-1,-1, -1, 0, 0,  0,1},
       {-1, 1,-1, -1, 0, 0,  0,0},
       {-1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0,  1,0},
       {-1,-1, 1, -1, 0, 0,  1,1},

       {-1,-1, 1,  0, 0, 1,  0,1},
       {-1, 1, 1,  0, 0, 1,  0,0},
       { 1, 1, 1,  0, 0, 1,  1,0},
       { 1,-1, 1,  0, 0, 1,  1,1},

       { 1,-1, 1,  1, 0, 0,  0,1},
       { 1, 1, 1,  1, 0, 0,  0,0},
       { 1, 1,-1,  1, 0, 0,  1,0},
       { 1,-1,-1,  1, 0, 0,  1,1},

       { 1,-1,-1,  0,-1, 0,  0,1},
       {-1,-1,-1,  0,-1, 0,  0,0},
       {-1,-1, 1,  0,-1, 0,  1,0},
       { 1,-1, 1,  0,-1, 0,  1,1},

       { 1, 1, 1,  0, 1, 0,  0,1},
       {-1, 1, 1,  0, 1, 0,  0,0},
       {-1, 1,-1,  0, 1, 0,  1,0},
       { 1, 1,-1,  0, 1, 0,  1,1},
    };
    const GLushort indices[]=
    {
         0, 1, 2,   2, 3, 0,
         4, 5, 6,   6, 7, 4,
         8, 9,10,  10,11, 8,
        12,13,14,  14,15,12,
        16,17,18,  18,19,16,
        20,21,22,  22,23,20,
    };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(CubeVertex), vertices);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(CubeVertex), (char*)vertices+3*sizeof(GLfloat));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof indices/sizeof*indices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);

    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

void blitFBToScreen()
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,frameTexture);
    if(dithering)
    {
        const GLint frameLoc=glGetUniformLocation(ditherProgram,"frame");
        if(frameLoc==-1)
            fprintf(stderr,"Failed to get location of frame uniform\n");
        glUseProgram(ditherProgram);
        glUniform1i(frameLoc,0);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,bayerMatrixTexture);
        const GLint bayerMatrixLoc=glGetUniformLocation(ditherProgram,"bayerMatrix");
        if(bayerMatrixLoc==-1)
            fprintf(stderr,"Failed to get location of Bayer matrix uniform\n");
        glUniform1i(bayerMatrixLoc,1);
    }
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
     glLoadIdentity();
     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
     glPushMatrix();
      glLoadIdentity();
      glOrtho(0,1,0,1,-1,1);
      glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,frameTexture);
      glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glTexCoord2f(0,0);
       glVertex2f(0,0);
       glTexCoord2f(0,1);
       glVertex2f(0,1);
       glTexCoord2f(1,1);
       glVertex2f(1,1);
       glTexCoord2f(1,0);
       glVertex2f(1,0);
      glEnd();
      glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
     glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glUseProgram(0);
}

void display()
{
    static GLboolean inited;
    if(!inited) inited=init();

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameFramebuffer);
    renderScene();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
    blitFBToScreen();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void reshape(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    const float aspect=(float)width/height;
    gluPerspective(180./4, aspect, 1, 100);
    if(aspect<1)
    {
        const GLfloat fixup[4*4]=
        {
            aspect, 0, 0, 0,
            0, aspect, 0, 0,
            0,    0,   1, 0,
            0,    0,   0, 1,
        };
        glMultMatrixf(fixup);
    }
    gluLookAt(0, 0,-5,
              0, 0, 0,
              0, 1, 0);

    // reinitialize FBO
    if(!frameTexture)
        glGenTextures(1,&frameTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,frameTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA32F,width,height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL);
    if(!frameFramebuffer)
        glGenFramebuffers(1,&frameFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameFramebuffer);
    if(!depthRenderBuffer)
        glGenRenderbuffers(1,&depthRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,depthRenderBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32,width,height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_RENDERBUFFER,depthRenderBuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D,frameTexture,0);
    GLenum status=glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if(status!=GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: framebuffer is incomplete: status=%#x\n",status);
        exit(10);
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{
    char winTitle[1024];
    switch(key)
    {
    case ' ':
        animating=!animating;
        snprintf(winTitle,sizeof winTitle,"Animation %sabled",animating?"en":"dis");
        break;
    case 'd':
        dithering=!dithering;
        snprintf(winTitle,sizeof winTitle,"Dithering %sabled",dithering?"en":"dis");
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
    glutSetWindowTitle(winTitle);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (1200, 900);
    glutCreateWindow ("Dithering test");
    if(glewInit()!=GLEW_OK)
    {
        fputs("Failed to init GLEW\n",stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    fputs("Press <SPACE> to toggle animation, 'd' to toggle dithering\n",stderr);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*you must have access to full-precision resulting colors.*" Nonsense. You simply need *more* precision than 8-bpp. You could render to an RGB10A2 image, or even RGBA16. Both are unsigned normalized formats, but offer 10 and 16 bits of precision. And both of them will be far less expensive than a full 32-bit float. And RGBA16 will offer more useful precision than RGBA16F.

Comment: @NicolBolas good point. I didn't even think of these formats, for me it was either 8-bit, or float32. Will have to edit this in.

Comment: "*you need proper support for such framebuffer configurations from video card.*" No, you just need to follow what OpenGL requires. OpenGL (3.0+) has a specific list of formats that are *required* for use by FBOs. None of the 3-channel formats are on that list (except for R11FG11FB10F), but the 4-channel formats are.

Comment: @NicolBolas while OpenGL 3.0+ imposes this requirement, `ARB_framebuffer_object` doesn't. With wide integral internal formats, this post-processing technique will work on OpenGL 2.0 hardware too.

Comment: "*With wide integral internal formats, this post-processing technique will work on OpenGL 2.0 hardware too.*" Assuming of course that the 2.0 hardware actually supports "wide integral internal formats". The same 3.0+ clause that imposes requirements on FBO support *also* is what *enforces* that certain internal formats be supported exactly as described. Without that clause, an implementation is free to implement `RGBA16` by substituting `RGBA8`.